# "Click" node other than anchor in Symfony2 functional test

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I have a `<li>` element, which has a click listener bound to it with jQuery. Is it possible to "click" this element with the client/crawler, to test the result. So far I have only found ways to follow anchor links.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do anything involving Javascript with a PHP Crawler like the one provided by Symfony2.

What you must look at is functional testing with a fake browser, like [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/testing.html).
With it, you can pilot a headless WebKit browser, 
and benefit of all the power of any async testing framework out there.

- click anything, throw events, inject code in the page
- wait for DOM node
- perform Ajax...

To name a few other, you should try:

- Jasmine
- Selenium
- Zombie.JS